# Однородные члены предложения. ошибки

Tags: определения

Добрый день!

Подскажите, пожалуйста, в данном предложении распространение ( после упражнений, которые он проводил с маленькой гантелей) относится только к глаголу "Разработалась" или еще к " Срослась" .

Пример:

**Кость руки  после перелома срослась и разработалась после упражнений, которые он проводил с маленькой гантелей.**

Comment: «Гантелей» — мн. число. Маленькой ганте́лью. Ваше «проводил» тоже не к месту.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Грамматически распространение относится к обоим к глаголам, семантически же предложение бессмысленно. Упражнения лишь помешают сращиванию кости, а разрабатывать можно только мышцы и суставы.

Comment: Ваш ответ побудил меня задать отдельный вопрос о связи обстоятельства с однородными сказуемыми: (http://rus.stackexchange.com/questions/430753/%d0%9e%d0%b1%d1%81%d1%82%d0%be%d1%8f%d1%82%d0%b5%d0%bb%d1%8c%d1%81%d1%82%d0%b2%d0%be-%d0%bf%d1%80%d0%b8-%d0%be%d0%b4%d0%bd%d0%be%d1%80%d0%be%d0%b4%d0%bd%d1%8b%d1%85-%d1%81%d0%ba%d0%b0%d0%b7%d1%83%d0%b5%d0%bc%d1%8b%d1%85). Хотелось бы получить на него ответ от Вас тоже.