# Обстоятельство при однородных сказуемых

Tags: синтаксис

**Он тяжело заболел и выздоровел после продолжительного лечения.**

- Чем является "после продолжительного лечения" в этом предложении? (По-моему, обстоятельством).
- Это обстоятельство относится только к одному из двух однородный сказуемых. 
  Является ли это ошибкой и почему? Для сравнения: **(1) Он заболел и быстро выздоровел. (2) Он тяжело заболел, но выздоровел после продолжительного лечения.** Эти два предложения кажутся мне корректными. В чем разница? Думаю, (1) в порядке слов, (2) в союзe. Хотелось бы получить ссылку на соответствующие правила.

Answer (score 3):

Не поняла, о каких правилах идёт речь. По-моему,структура предложения  ясна:простое предложение с однородными сказуемыми, в составе второго сказуемого обстоятельство"после лечения"(когда выздоровел?), распространённое определением "продолжительного".

Он не мог заболеть после продолжительного лечения, после лечения он мог только выздороветь, поэтому к первому сказуемому обстоятельство относиться не может.

Кроме того, некорректно говорить "обстоятельство согласуется", обстоятельство обычно связывается со сказуемым по способу управления или примыкания, лучше сказать "относится к одному из сказуемых", а именно ко второму.

Непонятно, о каком союзном слове идёт речь. И-соединительный союз, но - противительный, Вы об этом? Союзное слово присоединяет придаточное к главному предложению, другой роли у него нет.

Предложения для сравнения, возможно, более ясны по структуре, но и первое ошибки не содержит, хотя можно некую неясность убрать частицей только:Он тяжело заболел и выздоровел только после продолжительного лечения.

Comment: Спасибо!  Я исправил вопрос в соответствии с Вашими замечаниями.

Comment: Я думаю, вопрос, является ли это ошибкой, возник не только у меня. Вот @Марк Из утверждает, что "распространение" (?) относится к обоим глаголам: rus.stackexchange.com/questions/430746/…. Я надеялся, что где-то, например у Розенталя, прописано, что обстоятельство должно (или не обязано) относиться ко всем однородным сказуемым